# What is the word meaning "going on and on for miles and miles"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, participles

*Edit: I was walking down an intolerably long sidewalk one day, and every time a mounted another hill, I saw more of it seeming to stretch out before me. It got me to thinking: is there a word for "going on and on for miles and miles?"*

I'm looking for a single adjective that is aptly descriptive of a road that stretches for miles and never seems to end. I tried various words already; for example, it can't be *ramifying* because that word means *branching out in different directions.* Neither is it *redounding,* which has the idea of repetition. *Long* or *lengthy* would be too plain, while at the same time not saying enough.

So what I'm asking for is a single adjective (or present participle) that applies to a road or path and describes it as *stretching out ahead for miles with no end in sight* in a single word. Does this word even exist? If it does, what is it?

Example: *It was a long road, stretching and* ___*ing as it went, and it seemed like it would never end.*

Comment: If you can give us a sample sentence with a blank where the word should be, that would be helpful! :-)

Comment: Agreed with Kristina that a sample sentence would help clarify what you're asking for here. In general, you might try "perpetual", "eternal", "never-ending", "unending", or simply "endless".

Comment: Endless or boundless (hyperbole, but evocative), measureless...

Comment: Not sure about "boundless" - that would imply to me that it the road is also of infinite *width*.

Comment: roads don't change shape dynamically, so your example is likely to sound strange except as metaphor rather than description.

Comment: @Oldcat the metaphor _is_ descriptive of what the traveler sees.

Comment: What @Oldcat said - ***there isn't a word*** for the context where OP wants to use it, because it would strain figurative use of language to breaking point, infinity, and beyond.

Comment: @Mari-LouA nice catch. I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: Not sure you should change your question after you have received nine answers. What you could do, and it's allowed, is to answer your own question in the answer box. If people agree they'll upvote. Either way, you are the OP, and it's your choice. If you're happy with *lengthening* then that's the right answer for you! :)

Comment: What about **the apotheosis of roads**? The god-road...

Comment: Not sure, but it’s longer than one that merely goes on for kilometers and kilometers.

Comment: @The really? This is not the community for sarcasm.

Comment: I agree with Oldcat and FumbleFingers that there isn't really a word that fits in your example sentence, but perhaps not for the same reason they're citing. The phrase "__ing as it went" describes something *changing* either in the nature of the road itself or in the traveler's perception thereof; the extreme lengthiness of the road, however, is a constant. You may want to emphasize that the road's length is *increasingly surprising* to the traveler, but the phrase you've chosen wouldn't really work that way no matter what verb you pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Extensive**, **far-reaching**, **vast**.

The other answers that propose expressions of infinity, timelessness, perpetuity, unending, etc. are off-base, IMO.

The question says that this *extends for miles and miles*.

- It says nothing about going on *forever*. It does say no end *in sight*, but that is not the same as no end.
- It clearly is about space, not time.

Comment: So, _extending?_ I like it. I think that will work!

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink "Extending as it went" is non-idiomatic and semantically ambiguous. The most likely interpretation of that phrase would be that the road actually becomes longer as one is travelling along it, a la the train tracks at the end of the Wallace and Gromit short "The Wrong Trousers." (A fun image, but probably not what you meant.) As a reader I would be extremely unlikely to interpret the phrase metaphorically.

Comment: @Kyle, _seeming to extend before him as it went?_

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Maaaaaaaaybe, but even that suggests a dream-like literal stretching of the road in the traveler's imagination (though not in reality)--which is perhaps what you want. But I'd suggest tobyink's answer of "unfold": *seeming to unfold before him as it went*. This can use some further refinement: for instance, the "as it went" is still a little odd; "as he went" would be clearer.

Comment: @Kyle sometimes language is obviously figurative, if the plain sense doesn't make sense. I still think people are smart enough to recognize the difference. Besides, it's not as if I'm going to write this in a book or something.

Comment: @Brian I can't tell what you're going to do with it, and I don't see why it makes any difference. My interpretation of literal stretching isn't due to a lack of "smarts"; it's because that's the interpretation that fits best with the sentence.

Comment: @KyleStrand if you argue against it, it really doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Brian I didn't argue against it.

Answer (score 15):

**Interminable**

From the [Free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=interminable):

1. Being or seeming to be without an end; endless. ...
2. Tiresomely long; tedious.

> We've been driving for hours! Every time we round a bend or top a hill, the road just keeps going. It's interminable! It goes on forever!

**Edit** after the question was revised:

> It was a long road, stretching *interminably* as it went, and it seemed like it would never end.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for the picture of the road seeming to stretch out before you the more of it you traverse. See my example.

Comment: @Brian exactly :-)

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't picture the action I have in mind. Great word, though.

Comment: Ah, the Web is such a poor mind-reading vehicle!

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink I think you may not realize just how well this fits your question. "Stretching interminably into the distance" is about the most idiomatic (though possibly to the point of cliche) way to describe such a road that I can imagine.

Comment: @Kyle I'm going for a word, not an idiom.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink By "idiomatic" I mean natural-sounding, not using idioms. Individual word choices still need to be idiomatic.

Comment: @Kyle If every writer chose a word just because it sounded "natural," our literature would be very boring indeed. A great author will sometimes surprise his readers with a word choice.

Comment: @Brian Um.... No. Originality is not at odds with what I mean by natural-sounding. Linguistic innovative *must* sound natural in order to be successful.

Answer (score 5):

**Perpetual**
*adj. never ending or changing. Continuing or lasting for an indefinitely long time*
**Perpetually**
*adv. everlastingly; for all time; "rays...streaming perpetually from the sun"*
**Endless** and **Endlessly**
*having or seeming to have no end or limit* and  *continuing forever without end*

> It was a an endless road, stretching perpetually ahead of us, as if it would never end.
>
> It was a long road, stretching endlessly before me.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a single word that encapsulates both meanings: stretching out before me, _and_ unending.

Comment: "Endless" might be your best choice. I'm not convinced you can compress the meaning of *stretching ahead* and *unending* in a single word though.

Comment: Perpetual refers to time, not distance.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  Ever been on a journey that seemed it would never end? When you cover long distances, time is always involved.

Comment: @Mari-LouA A "perpetual road" would be one that never ceased to exist; it might be only a block long.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, my example used the adverb, perpetually, describing how the road stretch. It's used metaphorically as is the word  *endless*, in reality no road is really endless.

Answer (score 4):

**"unending"** is the simplest term for a road without end.

Comment: Sorry, but roads can't "unend", lol.

Comment: The Indy 500 racetrack can.

Answer (score 3):

*It as a long road, stretching and **unfolding** as it went, and it seemed like it would never end.*

(Or perhaps **unfurling**?)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something a little less appertaining to cloth, LOL.

Comment: I think they each work rather nicely for a road. They give the impression of a road that perhaps goes over hills, so that each time you crest a summit, a new length of the road is revealed.

Comment: But can it be used in the adjectival position, with no other explanation? _That was quite the unfolding road_ just doesn't have the same punch.

Comment: It **was** a long road... Not your fault, I know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No he means *it as* from the verb *to ave*

Answer (score 3):

You're making this much harder than it really is.

The word you are looking for is "endless", used like this:

"He traveled what seemed an endless road.
 It was indeed a long and tiresome road, stretching out before him as though it would never reach its destination"

Comment: Actually I meant them to be two separate examples of the same word.

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to "infinity" or "infinitely"...

> ***"It is a long road, stretching into infinity, as if it would never end."***

OR

> ***"It is a long road, stretching infinitely ahead, as if it would never end."***

Comment: Thanks, but is there a single word meaning "stretching into infinity"?

Comment: @brianJfink Yes. Infinite.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using "[ever-](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ever_23)" prefix in front of a desirable word. So you can give the additional meaning of "endless/continuous".

Thus, the best words that come to my mind are: **ever-stretching** and **ever-lengthening**. A less common but more creative one: **ever-elongating**.

They do not have a dictionary entry but they are used in literature.

Answer (score 1):

I like "continuous", "far-reaching", "incessant", or "enduring". "Never-ending" is a word, too.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for the picture of the road seeming to stretch out before you the more of it you traverse. See my example.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider:

> **unwinding**:  2 (archaic) :  to trace to the end *e.g. unwinding the labryinth and bringing the hero out* — Laurence Sterne

*[from m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwind)*

> Example: It was a long road, stretching and *unwinding* as it went,
>   and it seemed like it would never end.

Comment: How does _unwinding_ apply here?

Comment: Yes, my bad, it was the definition you posted that threw me off. You're thinking of something like _I saw the road unwinding into the distance_ right? I still wouldn't use it to imply that something is _interminable_ but yes, I see your point now. I edited your answer so I could retract my downvote (I can't unless the post is edited).

Comment: @terdon "Downvotes: downvotes everywhere." ;-)

Comment: This answer comes closest to my first thought, and I am surprised that it wasn't mentioned yet. Anybody who has ever heard the song should be able to fill in the blank in **the long and ____ road** by the Beatles? Yes, it is _winding_. And the song makes it clear that long and winding road (that leads to your door) is indeed seemingly neverending :)

Comment: @oerkelens Thanks for the moral support- at least it's only half as bad as the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The first word that came to mind is *spanning*, which according to [TFD's citation of AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/span) means

> To extend across in space or time

Because it is a transitive verb, it needs an object, as in:

> It was a long road, stretching and spanning the countryside as it went, and it seemed like it would never end.

*Span* seems to imply boundedness, as in "a bridge that spans the gorge" (from TFD). But in both cases, the "spanner" is limited by what it spans: The bridge spans as long as there is a gorge to span, and the road as long as there is countryside. Emphasizing the size of the countryside, I think, helps.

Because of *span*'s transitivity, the sentence above may be read as "the long road is stretching the countryside." If undesired, I remedied this by adding a preposition

> It was a long road, stretching across and spanning the (infinite) countryside as it went, and it seemed like it would never end.

Answer (score 1):

> It was a long road, stretching and ___ing as it went, and it seemed like it would never end.

If it has to be just one word to fill the blank, I'd go for "extending", or "unrolling", possibly "receding".

Comment: _Extending_ will work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfurling. In the subjective perspective of the driver or viewer it was expected to end at some point. This can add a psychological element as well.

Answer (score 0):

After much consideration of the answers proffered so far, I had an idea: could the correct answer be *lengthening,* as in these examples?

> He traveled what seemed a **lengthening** road.
>   It was indeed a long and tiresome road, stretching out and **lengthening** before him as though it would never reach its destination.

Comment: It's a stretch. If you wish to use lengthening I would suggest:  The road was long, in fact it seemed to be lengthening before his eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Ceaseless.

Unending.

*outstretching meandering as it went

Comment: I like *meandering* and was considering several nomadic words like it too, such as *ambling*, *sauntering*, *sojourning*, etc., the idea being that the distance to cover was so expansive that the road could not stay (figuratively speaking) in one place for long.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Probably couldn't assimilate the verisimilitude of my preeminently verbose vernaccuracy. C'est Le Vie

Answer (score 0):

*ad-infinitum* as in:

> The road stretched on *ad-infinitum*.

Answer (score 0):

Though I prefer "interminable" or almost any of the other words suggested, perhaps you would like "uroboric"/"ouroboric" the adjective derivation of "Ouroboros" - a circular symbol depicting a snake, or less commonly a dragon, swallowing its tail, as an emblem of wholeness or infinity, which embodies the concept of reaching forward as well as behind in an infinite circle.

Answer (score 0):

converging or narrowing, to indicate the perspective

It was a long road, stretching and narrowing as it went, and it seemed like it would never end.

Comment: My emphasis, if you've read my question in its entirety, is the successive discovery of additional length, not its apparently getting smaller in the distance.